# move "disabled" class using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this list-group (bootstrap) and I want to move the "disabled" class between those links,

```
<div class="list-group">
  <a href="#" onclick="form1()" class="list-group-item disabled">
    Particular
  </a>
  <a href="#" onclick="form2()" class="list-group-item">Distribuidores</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="form3()" class="list-group-item">Incidencias</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="form4()" class="list-group-item">Grandes cantidades</a>
</div>
```

i.e. if I click on the second link, the "disabled" should move from the first link to the second, so we will have something like:

```
<div class="list-group">
    <a href="#" onclick="form1()" class="list-group-item">Particular</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="form2()" class="list-group-item disabled">Distribuidores</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="form3()" class="list-group-item">Incidencias</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="form4()" class="list-group-item">Grandes cantidades</a>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not a property, but a class?

Comment: yes, you're right, fixed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a method like this:

```
function setDisabled(index) {
  var links = document.querySelectorAll(".list-group-item")
  for (var i = 0, link; (link = links[i]) != undefined; i++) {
    link.className = "list-group-item" + (i == index ? " disabled" : "");
  }
}
```

This method could be called from the methods you're using to handle the clicks with the index parameter being the zero based index of the element. You could also add an id to each of the links and use that instead to find the link that was clicked.

Basically, it creates an array of all elements with the "list-group-item" class and resets their class attribute to only have that class. For the link that was clicked it also adds the "disabled" class.

Comment: Please avoid magical numbers in DOM queries. Ideally, similar functions should also be one with a parameter in a way that the page can expand without much effort.